# fluent nhibernate automapping configuration does't work

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Fluent Configuration is

```
FluentConfiguration fc = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connectionString)               
            );
```

Mapping Configuration is

```
fc.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => 
         cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, currentSessionContextClass))
  .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => 
         cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.CommandTimeout, "120")
   );                

fc.Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<BasicEntity>(autoMappingConf)          
               .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AccountMappingOverride>()
               .Conventions.Add(
                    DefaultCascade.SaveUpdate(),
                    new DefaultStringLengthConvention(),
                    new DefaultDecimalConvention()))           
                );
        return fc;
```

Inner Exceptions are Database in not configured with database method.
Also incomplete Mapping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory in fluent Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721980/an-invalid-or-incomplete-configuration-was-used-while-creating-a-sessionfactory)

Answer (score -1):

I just change the Position

```
fc.Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<BasicEntity>

(autoMappingConf)          

               .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AccountMappingOverride>()
               .Conventions.Add(
                    DefaultCascade.SaveUpdate(),
                    new DefaultStringLengthConvention(),
                    new DefaultDecimalConvention()))           
                );


fc.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => 

         cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, 

currentSessionContextClass))

  .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => 

         cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.CommandTimeout, "120")

   );             

return fc;
```